# in mysql, add the column after the other column if exists

Tags: mysql, alter

how can it?

I found it for check column exists

```
(
SELECT 1 FROM Information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'db' 
AND table_name = 'table' 
AND column_name = 'the other column'
)
```

and add the column after the other column

```
ALTER TABLE 'table' ADD 'the column' VARCHAR(14) DEFAULT NULL AFTER 'the other column'
```

Comment: Put both statements in a stored procedure.

Comment: you have error?

Comment: Also, use backticks around table and column names, not single quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: I will run this code to each database had a different structure, but I want to add the column only if had a specific column

Barmer: that was just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give the name of the db in which the table exists:-

```
ALTER TABLE db.table ADD the_column VARCHAR(14) DEFAULT NULL AFTER the_other_column
```

It worked for me try this and let me know where it is failing

Comment: I will run this code to each database had a different structure,
but I want to add the column only if had a specific column.